# Image write using webservices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, image-upload

I'm working on rest webservices (rails), Mobile team sending request and I need to create  image, Somebudy help me how I can write Image using binary data as I have binary data in my params. I tried many things but didn't get any luck.

Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

You can try image magick, I am not sure it will do the conversion.

But you should not be sending binary images... use multipart

Comment: How can send data as multipart by mobile team?

Comment: I'm dependent on mobile team, And I knew it , I need request with multipart.. Thanks for your response.